# How to obtain significance tests (/standard errors) that are still valid after variable selection?

Tags: statistical-significance, mixed-model, feature-selection, standard-error, aic

I want to do variable selection via information criteria like the AIC or BIC. However, I am struggling with how I can obtain valid standard errors after doing this such that I can properly interpret the results of my models (e.g. multi-level model).

Any suggestions on how I can obtain valid standard errors after variable selection?

EDIT: I want to do variable selection (that is use AIC) to select the appropriate lag orders and possibly also exclude some control variables that seem unimportant.

Comment: Before anyone answers that can you explain why variable selection is a good idea in your context?  It is frought with huge downsides, especially loss of predictive discrimination, reduced reproducibility, high instability in features selected.